# How to use variable value in HTML SCRIPT tag as C# variable

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var statusPara = new Array(
1,
1,
20,
20000,
13182,
"3.11.1 Build 100312 Rel.42991n ",
"WR740N v1 00000000",
0,
0,0 );
</SCRIPT>
```

In C#, how can I get "statusPara" and use it as C# variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to insert this array as a JavaScript variable from your C#? As in using Razor markup in ASP? Or take a JavaScript variable from a page and hand it over to your server? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I get that JavaScript variable from a page(I get html code by sending a GET request) and I want to show its value in my own C# form

Comment: First off, I would recommend you edit your question to provide more details that answer the questions I asked, as it currently stands your question is very unclear.

Comment: So that variable exists on the page, you then use a get request to send a load of text to your server and within that text exists the variable? If so, I would recommend using `JSON.stringify()` to format the data you need to send and then parse that on the server.

Comment: I have no server, I just have html code. That code is a part of html body (I get a page, view its source and see it) But that variable is only used in its html code. are there any ways to parse (or something's like that) those variables from html source code to C# variable then I can use it as C# varible :)

Comment: There is no reasonable way to run C# on a webpage. If you want to copy the text from a webpage and then parse it to retrieve data from it then you need to look into string parsing and splitting (Splitting the text into an array of strings that you can then use). If you want to create code during runtime then you need to look into reflection. Both of those would require more specific and better explained questions.

Comment: thanks for your help @douglasg14b :)